# Ubuntu software showing when I logged in in the morning and logged out in the evening

Tags: ubuntu, scheduling, planning

I want an Ubuntu package that will show when I raised from the bed and turned on or unlocked screensaver of my computer, and when yesterday I stopped to use it, to know my sleeping habits better than I know now.

Comment: maybe you could put some weight sensors under the legs of your bed (like the kind they use in bathroom scales) and use the data from that to track when you are in/out of bed. that could be more reliable in more edge cases where you dont. for logins to your system, maybe /var/log/auth.log would help?

Comment: @DeveloperACE No, /var/log/auth.log shows root not the user sessions on my Ubuntu

Comment: the command `last` ([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390201/how-to-see-login-history#390204)) might also be helpful for showing something close to logins as well.

Comment: If it's going to sleep, you can use this https://askubuntu.com/questions/841197/logs-of-ubuntu-going-into-sleep-and-waking-up Otherwise, you can find similar kind of logs for shutdowns etc.

Comment: @Destroy666 It goes to sleep only after a hour of inactivity. Well, I can subtract a hour

Comment: Inactivity was not included in your question. I'm not following in any case - so you manually log out, but you can't manually put it to sleep instead? Or do you just leave the machine logged in because you fall asleep? Either way, all of these methods seem weird and inaccurate. Mediocre cheap Chinese sleep tracker would do wonders in comparison.